# Как в loop скрыть записи с одинаковыми заголовками?

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть 2 одинаковых марки машин, мне нужно что бы показывало только одну из них. Вторую же должно просто игнорировать в loop'е.

Comment: ничего не понятно. хотя видимо вам надо запоминать в переменной предыдущее значение и сравнивать